# Android new Wear OS 2.0 requirements

Tags: wear-os

i have a few questions with Googles new announcement about wear OS

https://9to5google.com/2021/02/12/wear-os-legacy-apps/

So we currently have the wear apk bundled in the app.

the requirements say it needs to be set to standalone in manifest.

then it will show in app store

So questions are:

1.does it need to have all the functions that are in the phone?like calling api's and commands...

2.they say it needs to be compatible with IOS?

3.if its android watch and paired to IOS phone.does that mean you need to do like a hybrid app?or you can make it that it is not compatible?

Thx guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The announcement relates to phasing out companion apps (where the apk is bundled) and shifting towards standalone wear apps that can dynamically enable additional functionality if compatible phone app is found. As for listing on the watch play store, I don't think they've changed their position on this too much, even before this announcement the indication was always that companion apps would not be published, now they won't even be discoverable.

iOS compatibility has also always been a requirement for publishing in the play store for wear, which means that you need to have some additional form of wearable<->handheld communication besides the Android-specific Data Layer.

If you've developed your app as a standalone app that carries out its own network communication, then this shouldn't be a big hurdle. If you've always been reliant on the tight coupling with a companion app via the Data Layer, then this will take some rearchitecting and extension of your wear app. This is outlined in more detail [here](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data/network-access).